# How to Convert a Stream to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, stream, memorystream

In My code try:

[image: data expected]

Stream Content

```
engine.SetDocument((MemoryStream)content); //No work
```

Or

```
var a = new MemoryStream();
engine.SetDocument(content.CopyTo(a)); //Error
```

Comment: Looks like it wants a MemoryStream.  Try `SetDocument(a);`

Comment: @AndresCarvajal `Stream` is abstract - so it must be something more specific in reality.  It may or may not be a `MemoryStream`, so casting is not safe.  What are you needing to do that requires a `Memorystream`?

Answer (score 8):

CopyTo is a void method so returns nothing, try the following:

```
var a = new MemoryStream();
content.CopyTo(a);
engine.SetDocument(a);
```

Comment: this one is smooth

Answer (score 3):

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
{
   byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
   file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
   ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
}
```